# Bind to ng-model filter dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to filter questions out by clicking on their associated category name checkbox. Ex: only questions with category X will be shown if only category X checkbox is checked.

I'm able to bind the names `Cat1`, `Cat2`, etc directly to the `catfilters` object:

```
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="catfilters.Cat1" /> Cat 1
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="catfilters.Cat2" /> Cat 2

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="q in questions | bycategory:catfilters">{{q.question.cat_id}}</li>
    </ul>
```

This works.

---

However, I want to dynamically create the category checkboxes from a list in the controller, and bind them to the `catfilters` object:

```
    $scope.cats = [
        'Cat1',
        'Cat2',
        'Cat3'
    ];

    //c is 'Cat1', 'Cat2', etc...
    <div ng-repeat="c in cats">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="catfilters.c">{{c}}</span>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="q in questions | bycategory:catfilters">{{q.question.cat_id}}</li>
    </ul>
```

But for some reason, this will not apply the filtering. I am not getting any errors though.

**Note: I've also tried looking up by indexed property:**

```
<div ng-repeat="c in cats">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="catfilters[c]">{{c}}</span>
</div>
```

This also does not work

---

**Filter**:

```
angular
    .module('DDE').
        filter('bycategory', function() {
            return function (questions, categories) {

                var items = {
                    categories: categories,
                    out: []
                };

                angular.forEach(questions, function (value, key) {
                    if (this.categories[value.question.cat_id] === true) {
                        this.out.push(value);
                    }
                }, items);
                return items.out;
            };
        }
    );
```

Comment: can you provide sample plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

`catfilters.c` looks for a property called `c` in `catfilters`, regardless of if you have a variable `c` elsewhere.

Try looking it up by the indexed property `catfilters[c]` instead.

```
//c is 'Cat1', 'Cat2', etc...
<div ng-repeat="c in cats">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="catfilters[c]">{{c}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GqTuVg8ZjZ0250t3DQz7?). I implement using

```
     <div ng-repeat="input in inputs">
      <input type="text" ng-model="filter[input]">
     </div>
```

and

```
     $scope.inputs = ['foo','bar'];
       $scope.filter={
         'foo':"Foo",
         'bar':"Bar"
        }
```

It is working fine (which i think is similar to your scenario).There must be something error in your implementation.